# Splitting a string and inserting the parts in the correct columns inside a table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to build a fact table with sql server. It currently looks like this:

```
[Item]  [Variant Descr.] [Variant Order] [Dim_Colour] [Dim_Size] [Dim_Style]
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
01         NAVY/44        COLOUR/SIZE     NULL         NULL       NULL
02         BLACK/S4       COLOUR/STYLE    NULL         NULL       NULL
```

I need to split the String in [Variant Descr.] and insert the parts into the correct Dim_ Column so the table will eventually look like this:

```
[Item]  [Variant Descr.] [Variant Order] [Dim_Colour] [Dim_Size] [Dim_Style]
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
01         NAVY/44        COLOUR/SIZE     NAVY         44       NULL
02         BLACK/S4       COLOUR/STYLE    BLACK        NULL     S4
```

The problem is that the parts of [Variant Order] and the number of parts of [Variant Descr.] may vary for each row. So I basically need to do something like:

1. Get the String before the '/' in [Variant Descr.]
2. Get the String before the '/' in [Variant Order]
3. Insert the first value into the column specified by the second value
4. Do this for all parts of [Variant Descr.]
5. Do this for every row in the table

I have already tried to solve this with a user-defined function, only to find out that I cannot use dynamic SQL within a UDF.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Cheers!

Comment: which sql-server version you are using?

Comment: You can try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/56254171/10532500

Comment: Are `/SIZE` and `/STYLE` the only options? Might there be a case with `/STYLE/SIZE` and/or `/SIZE/STYLE` carrying three values at once? is the sorting fixed or do you expect values like `SIZE/COLOUR` too?

Comment: They are not the only options. The allows for up to 16 different options. Any item may carry 0 to 16 values. The sorting is not fixed either. I am using SQL Server 2016

Comment: @Stephan So, you have a different column for each different option - `[Dim_xxxx]` for `xxx` option?

Comment: @Zhorov: Yes, the columns are generated dynamically for every distnict value of [Variant Order] in the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible approach is to split the texts in [Variant Descr.] and [Variant Order] columns and update the table with dynamic statement.
Although using `STRING_SPLIT()` is the first choice starting with SQL Server 2016, this function is not an option in this case, because the order of the substrings is not guaranteed.
A working solution is to use `OPENJSON()` - columns values are transformed into a valid `JSON` object (`'NAVY/44'` is translated into `'["NAVY", "44"]'` for example) and substrings are retrieved using `OPENJSON()`.

Input:

```
CREATE TABLE #Data (
   [Item] varchar(10),  
   [Variant Descr.] varchar(50), 
   [Variant Order] varchar(50), 
   [Dim_Colour] varchar(50),   
   [Dim_Size] varchar(50),  
   [Dim_Style] varchar(50)
)
INSERT INTO #Data 
   ([Item], [Variant Descr.], [Variant Order], [Dim_Colour], [Dim_Size], [Dim_Style])
VALUES
   ('01', 'NAVY/44',    'COLOUR/SIZE',       NULL, NULL, NULL),
   ('02', 'BLACK/S4',   'COLOUR/STYLE',      NULL, NULL, NULL),
   ('03', 'NAVY/44/S4', 'COLOUR/SIZE/STYLE', NULL, NULL, NULL),
   ('04', 'GREEN',      'COLOUR',            NULL, NULL, NULL)
```

T-SQL:

```
-- Dynamic statement
DECLARE @stm nvarchar(max) = N''
SELECT @stm = @stm + 
   N'UPDATE #Data ' +
   N'SET ' + 
   QUOTENAME('Dim_' + j1.[value]) +
   N' = ''' +
   j2.[value] +
   N''' WHERE Item = ''' +
   d.Item +
   N'''; '
FROM #Data d
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(CONCAT('["', REPLACE([Variant Order], '/', '","'), '"]')) j1 
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(CONCAT('["', REPLACE([Variant Descr.], '/', '","'), '"]')) j2
WHERE j1.[key] = j2.[key]

-- Execution and output
EXEC (@stm)
SELECT *
FROM #Data
```

Output:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Item    Variant Descr.  Variant Order     Dim_Colour    Dim_Size    Dim_Style
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
01      NAVY/44         COLOUR/SIZE       NAVY          44  
02      BLACK/S4        COLOUR/STYLE      BLACK                     S4
03      NAVY/44/S4      COLOUR/SIZE/STYLE NAVY          44          S4
04      GREEN           COLOUR            GREEN
```

Comment: I like this very *straight-forward* approach... +1 from my side

Comment: Thanks! This looks great! Your sample Code runs fine. However, in my testing environment I get an error: `Message 207, Invalid column name 'Dim_'.`

Comment: @Stephan Probably wrong data (according to the format in your question). I'm able to reproduce this error with the following statement: `INSERT INTO #Data (..) VALUES ('04', 'RED/44', '/SIZE', NULL, NULL, NULL)`. Thanks.

Comment: @Stephan, you can modify Zhorov's statement to a `SELECT ... INTO #tmpTbl` instead. You can proceed with this #tmpTbl as a staging table and do the updates from there. A generic approach like in my answer will be more tolerant with unexpected values...

Comment: You are right - if I filter out the row with no [Variant Description] the error diappears. It works fine for rows where [Item] is an integer. I still get `Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '1972-S' to data type int ` for items containing characters like '1972-S' Thanks a ton for your help so far

Comment: @Stephan Sorry, `Item` is a `varchar` column, so I need to add `'` before and after `d.Item` - ... `N''' WHERE Item = ''' + d.Item + N'''; '`. See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp')IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #temp

CREATE TABLE #temp (
            [Item] INT,  
            [Variant Descr.] VARCHAR(100),
            [Variant Order] VARCHAR(100) ,
            [Dim_Colour] VARCHAR(100),
            [Dim_Size]INT ,
            [Dim_Style]  VARCHAR(100)
            )

INSERT INTO  #temp
SELECT 01,'NAVY/44' ,'COLOUR/SIZE' ,NULL,NULL,NULL UNION ALL
SELECT 02,'BLACK/S4','COLOUR/STYLE',NULL,NULL,NULL

SELECT * FROM #temp

UPDATE o 
SET     o.[Dim_Colour]  = dt.Dim_Colour, 
        o.Dim_Size = dt.Dim_Size,
        o.Dim_Style = dt.Dim_Style
FROM #temp o
INNER JOIN
(    

SELECT [Item],  [Variant Descr.], [Variant Order] ,
            SUBSTRING([Variant Descr.],0,CHARINDEX('/',[Variant Descr.])) AS [Dim_Colour]   
           ,CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING([Variant Descr.],CHARINDEX('/',[Variant Descr.])+1,LEN ([Variant Descr.]))) = 1 AND [Variant Order] = 'COLOUR/SIZE'   
                  THEN SUBSTRING([Variant Descr.],CHARINDEX('/',[Variant Descr.])+1,LEN ([Variant Descr.]))
                  ELSE NULL END AS [Dim_Size]
           ,CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING([Variant Descr.],CHARINDEX('/',[Variant Descr.])+1,LEN ([Variant Descr.]))) <> 1 AND [Variant Order] ='COLOUR/STYLE'
                  THEN SUBSTRING([Variant Descr.],CHARINDEX('/',[Variant Descr.])+1,LEN ([Variant Descr.]))
                  ELSE NULL END AS [Dim_Style]
      FROM  #temp i
)dt ON dt.[Item] = o.[Item]

SELECT * FROM  #temp
```

Result

```
Item    Variant Descr.  Variant Order       Dim_Colour  Dim_Size    Dim_Style
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1       NAVY/44         COLOUR/SIZE            NAVY         44        NULL
2       BLACK/S4        COLOUR/STYLE           BLACK       NULL       S4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get required output by -

```
select [item] ,
      [variant descr],[variant order],
      left([variant descr],charindex('/', [variant descr]) - 1) AS [Dim_Colour],
      CASE WHEN [variant order] like '%/SIZE' THEN SUBSTRING([variant descr], CHARINDEX('/', [variant descr]) +1, 100)
       ELSE '' END  AS [Dim_Size],
      CASE WHEN [variant order] like '%/STYLE' THEN SUBSTRING([variant descr], CHARINDEX('/', [variant descr]) +1, 100)
       ELSE '' END  AS [Dim_Style]
    from your_table_name
```

Answer (score 0):

And here is a fully generic approach to split this up (thx Zhorov for the MCVE!)

```
CREATE TABLE #Data (
   [Item] varchar(10),  
   [Variant Descr.] varchar(50), 
   [Variant Order] varchar(50), 
   [Dim_Colour] varchar(50),   
   [Dim_Size] varchar(50),  
   [Dim_Style] varchar(50)
)
INSERT INTO #Data 
   ([Item], [Variant Descr.], [Variant Order], [Dim_Colour], [Dim_Size], [Dim_Style])
VALUES
   ('01', 'NAVY/44',       'COLOUR/SIZE',       NULL, NULL, NULL),
   ('02', 'BLACK/S4',      'COLOUR/STYLE',      NULL, NULL, NULL),
   ('03', 'NAVY/44/S4',    'COLOUR/SIZE/STYLE', NULL, NULL, NULL),
   ('04', 'GREEN/1/2/3/4', 'COLOUR/aNewOne/SIZE/EvenMore/STYLE', NULL, NULL, NULL);
GO

WITH Casted AS
(
    SELECT *
          ,CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(d.[Variant Order],'/','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML) AS OrderXml
          ,CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(d.[Variant Descr.],'/','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML) AS DescrXml
    FROM #Data d
)
SELECT c.Item
      ,A.Position 
      ,c.OrderXml.value('/x[sql:column("Position")][1]','nvarchar(max)') AS OrderKey
      ,c.DescrXml.value('/x[sql:column("Position")][1]','nvarchar(max)') AS DescrValue
FROM Casted c
CROSS APPLY(SELECT TOP(SELECT c.OrderXml.value('count(/*)','int')) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY(SELECT NULL)) FROM master..spt_values) A(Position)

GO

DROP TABLE #Data;
```

The result

```
+------+----------+----------+------------+
| Item | Position | OrderKey | DescrValue |
+------+----------+----------+------------+
| 02   | 1        | COLOUR   | BLACK      |
+------+----------+----------+------------+
| 02   | 2        | STYLE    | S4         |
+------+----------+----------+------------+
| 04   | 1        | COLOUR   | GREEN      |
+------+----------+----------+------------+
| 04   | 2        | aNewOne  | 1          |
+------+----------+----------+------------+
| 04   | 3        | SIZE     | 2          |
+------+----------+----------+------------+
| 04   | 4        | EvenMore | 3          |
+------+----------+----------+------------+
| 04   | 5        | STYLE    | 4          |
+------+----------+----------+------------+
| 01   | 1        | COLOUR   | NAVY       |
+------+----------+----------+------------+
| 01   | 2        | SIZE     | 44         |
+------+----------+----------+------------+
| 03   | 1        | COLOUR   | NAVY       |
+------+----------+----------+------------+
| 03   | 2        | SIZE     | 44         |
+------+----------+----------+------------+
| 03   | 3        | STYLE    | S4         |
+------+----------+----------+------------+
```

You can proceed with *conditional aggregation* or with a `PIVOT` approach.

The idea in short:

I use a cast to XML to allow to reach the fragment by its position.
Furthermore I use `CROSS APPLY` together with `ROW_NUMBER`, which will return a list of numbers depending on the count of the current row's list of fragments. This number is now used within `sql:column()` to read the fitting fragments *side-by-side*.